# i can't set variable in my php code

Tags: php

In the program below, I want `$pid=23` for first time, and after I want to get the value from the query string that i am passing.  But I can't get it to work. I tried with this

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$pid=23;
$pid=$_REQUEST['prod_id'];
$qr=mysql_query("SELECT prod_id,prod_name,prod_desc,prod_img FROM product_tbl 
where prod_id='".$pid."'");
$rw=mysql_fetch_array($qr);
?>
```

or

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$pid=$_REQUEST['prod_id'];//undifine query string error
if($pid='')
{
$pid=23;
$qr=mysql_query("SELECT prod_id,prod_name,prod_desc,prod_img FROM product_tbl 
where prod_id='".$pid."'");
$rw=mysql_fetch_array($qr);
?>
```

I have no idea how it can be done.

Comment: how you are passing 'prod_id' ?

Comment: What you really want to do over here ?

Comment: Show us you javascript/form related to this script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumptions about your requirement is correct please try this way 
No product id in request 
https://example.com
with product id 
https://example.com?prod_id=20

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if (isset($_GET['prod_id'])) {
  $pid = $_GET['prod_id'];
}
else {
  $pid = 23;
}
$qr=mysql_query("SELECT prod_id,prod_name,prod_desc,prod_img FROM product_tbl 
where prod_id='".$pid."'");
$rw=mysql_fetch_array($qr);
?>
```

Comment: thanx Dabish for your answer.